# integrate WordPress blog into MVC3 website

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have a website built in MVC3.

I want to integrate a wordpress blog so users are able to still enter blogs using this but shows on the MVC site. Is this possible?

Comment: This needs more info - what exactly do you want to integrate where? Are both things running on the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP should run fine and independently if you just stick it in `/blog` folder in your web root. Just make sure your server is configured to not-rewrite actual files and directories to your framework, which is most of the time default.